# Computer wont boot. No picture on monitor, no usb power plus more

Tags: windows-7, boot, graphics-card, power-supply

Tried to turn on his stationary computer after being turned off for one night. It is a few years old, components are somewhat strong (Was built to be a gaming pc).

No picture on screen, tried two different monitors. So i cant debug myself. No USB power, but the PS/2 port is getting power. Red light on graphics card when i plug in a DVI cable regardless of whether the pc is on or off. Fans are running as normal as far as i can tell.

Components: EVGA e-GeForce 8800GTS, Asus P5K3 Deluxe, Intel Core 2 Quad(I think so), Chieftec PSU (Not sure wich model), Samsung HD252KJ Harddrive and 2 Corsair XMS3 DDR3 Ram sticks at a total of 2gb ram.

Windows 7, installed update when turned off yesterday (Last thing he did before it got how it is now).

The PC has been turned off and inactive for 3 years before booting it back up 4 days ago. It has been working fine until today.

I believe the computer might be stuck at BIOS wich can explain why only the PS/2 port is working. This might be because of a failed update. 
But that does not explain why there is no picture on the monitor. I hope not, but there might be a hardware problem somewhere. 
When i looked into the computer to check what components he have i noticed a large amount of dust in the graphics card cooling fan (And a few other fans, but not as bad as the graphics card), so maybe its been overheating the last 4 days.

This is all i know, so im stuck at knowing absolutely nothing about why it wont show any picture. I can try to clean out some dust and then try to boot it, but i would rather not try and boot it if you guys think it might be a hardware problem. I want to limit damage as much as possible.

**Update:**

POST 1 long 3 short beeps.

**Update 2:**

Fixed it myself. A quick search on google revealed that it was the graphics card. Thankfully it was not broken and all it took was plugging out the graphics card, some cleaning with a cotton swab and plugging it back in.

Hopefully this will be of help to other people.

Answer (score 1):

I found the manual for your motherboard from the [support site for your motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5K3_DeluxeWiFiAP/HelpDesk_Manual/).

On page 3-1:

> **One continuous beep followed by three short beeps:**
>   No VGA Detected

Sorry, but it looks like your video card is dead. Try it in another machine if you wish, but it looks like it's dead. It's lived a long life.

Answer (score 0):

1 long, 3 short beeps indicates a problem with your graphics card, according to [ASUS's beep table](http://support.asus.com/pcassistant/pdf/BeepTable_en-us.pdf).

They suggest reinstalling the graphics card, switching it to a different PCIe slot (though they incorrectly state 'DIMM slot', ahem), clean the PCIe connector, or replace your graphics card. I'd suggest also ensuring that any PCIe power connectors are properly plugged in, if appropriate.